# Which statement will change value of x to 60 in C programing?

Tags: c

```
int *p;
int x;
int k;
x = 30;
k = x;
p = &x;
```

After these statements, which of the following statements will the value of x to 60? My answer is 1. But I'm not sure if I am correct,   because seem like other answer is correct too. Please gives some explanation.

```
1. k = 60;
2. *k = 60;
3. p = 60;
4. *p = 60;
```

Comment: Which other answer do you think is correct and why?

Comment: You know, you can write a simple program to test it ?

Comment: we're not going to do your homework for you, but here's a tip: your answer is wrong.

Comment: Not only is @l3x's comment spot on... clearly you're taking a programming class. If you find it easier, or more desirable, or faster, etc., to ask random strangers than to write a simple program to test it, you should consider a different course track.

Comment: Why did you answer 1?  Why do you think changing the value of `k` affects the value of `x`?  Which other answer did you think could be correct, and why?

Comment: When you push that button labelled `Ask Question`, you're supposed to ask a question that we can answer. But you didn't really ask us a question. You told us the question you have to answer and what you think the answer might be, but didn't provide any reasoning we can support or criticize and didn't ask us anything specific. That makes this a poor question for this site.

Comment: There is only one correct answer and it is not 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an explanation:

```
int *p; //declares a pointer to an integer
int x;  //declares an integer called x
int k;  //declares an integer called k

//at this point all values are uninitialized and could contain anything

x = 30; //the numerical value 30 is assigned to x
k = x;  //the contents of x(30) is assigned to k
p = &x; //the address of int x is stored in p

//now all values have valid and reliable values
```

Now let me explain what each line you described does:

```
k = 60; //assigns value 60 to variable k

*k = 60; //attempts to dereference k which is a non pointer type (compile time error)

p = 60;  //attempts to assign the value 60 to a pointer p this is NOT what you want

*p = 60; //dereferences pointer p(which points to x) and sets the value 60 to it
```

the last line has the same effect as `x=60;` so it is the correct answer.

`k=60;` will not affect the content of `x`, because `x` and `k` are different variables they each have their own separate memory. `k=x;` will simply copy the contents of `x` into `k`, it will not make the variables aliases of each other.

Comment: I am tempted to upvote this well documented answer, but encouraging such questions is counterproductive.

Comment: In my humble opinion, it was a valid (albeit elementary) question, but due to the poor phrasing of the question and the title, it is unlikely that it will help anyone else.

Comment: After re-reading the question, I agree it is a rather naive question but not a blunt call for homework on demand. It this context, your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compile it and run it in a debugger via single step to see how it works.

Comment: You're right but this is not an acceptable answer on Stack Overflow. It's an acceptable _comment_ but you haven't yet earned the reputation to permit leaving comments. Please keep this in mind for future posts.

Comment: @mah What do you do if the only possible answer to a question doesn't deserve to be an answer?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think you probably mean "doesn't deserve to be answered"? In that case, you vote to close if you can justify that, or you post a comment telling them why, or you just move on to another question. I agree that the question doesn't deserve to be answered, and I'm glad you chose to delete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not 1.  You're close,  answers 2 and 3 don't make sense.

```
p = &x
```

p points to the memory address of x so setting

```
p = 60
```

would be setting its address to 60 which is not what you want.

```
k = x;
```

Changing k will not change x because k doesn't store the memory of x, it has instead copied the value of x.

```
*p = 60
```

**The value that p is pointing to equals 60, in this case p is pointing to the address of x**

So when ever the **value** at the **address** of x changes, *p changes or vice versa.

**The key point is *p is pointing the value at the  memory address of x, so changing *p changes x**

The answer is 4.